# jQuery/JS selecting element on click to change with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web-applications

So I've got some code and how it works now is as follows: 
- `Press a button`
- Fill in fields
- Fields append new

to an

My dilemma is that I need to be able to change the `background-color` of each

at any given moment. Unfortunately I'm working with a closed source application so revealing code isn't an option, however what I'm trying to do is create a system where it'll let me click on an

and then save the selection to a JS variable at which point I can press one of three buttons on the dashboard to change the color of said

Is this at all possible? I've tried jQuery's `.closest()` and `.find()` methods with no avail

Any help would be appriciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you shall try with various selection methods. like .parent(), .child(), .siblings() and also .find(). just work around these to target your selection.